# Phonegap blackberry jad file testing

Tags: cordova, testing, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

In the windows I wrote one application and generated phone gap blackberry build in the cloud. I got .jad file for testing.

For testing i downloaded the blackberry simulator and vm player. In the vm i opened blackberry simulator. Here i didn't get any option to get the installation. Please guide me how can i do the testing in the simulator. I downloaded the **momentics-2.1-201406041640.win32.x86.setup** and installed. when deploy through cmd prompt i didn't succeed.

Please help me how can i test that application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant change in development environment between BBOS (version numbers up to 7) and BB10. BB10 does not use the JAD format so you will not be able to test them using BB10 simulators which will be install by Momentics. So you need to decide which platform you are developing and testing for.

Simulators for BBOS should still be available from BlackBerry at this location: https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477